# Creating an Ethernet bridge like application using Python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I have tried several way to capture all packets using various forms of sockets. For example:

```
packets = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))

host_s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW , socket.ntohs(ETH_P_ALL))
host_s.bind((HOST,0))
host_s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 0)

us = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
us.bind((HOST,1900))
```

But none of these methods capture all the packets. I simply want to have something that passes all packets from one network interface to another, yet allows me to manipulate the packets any way I desire.

Specifically, what I am working on the moment is something to allow 802.1x bypass by essentially created my own conn table and essentially create a NAT but at layer 2.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What packets aren't you seeing?

Comment: I am seeing DHCP packets, no SDDP, ARP, MDNS packets. I even tried binding to port 1900 to see if I could pick up the SSDP packets.